# When the developer console is open in chrome, why does onmouseover stop working?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, google-chrome

When the developer console is open in chrome, why does onmouseover stop working?
It instead fires onclick.

Consider this simple example.  It resizes the image onMouseOver when the console is closed, but only on click when the console is open

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function over(x) { x.style.height="64px"; }
    function out(x) {  x.style.height="32px"; }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out(this)" src="animage.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have the console opened in a separate window, with that other window being focused, rather than the browser window? Then, that's why.

Comment: It's in the same window anchored at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

which Google Chrome version do you have?
For me it works without any issues: http://jsfiddle.net/MXTQJ/

```
<script>
function over(x) { x.style.height="64px"; }
function out(x) {  x.style.height="32px"; }
</script>
<img onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out(this)" src="animage.png" />
```

Comment: Version 27.0.1453.93 (OS X 10.7.5).   Occurred to me that maybe I should post it to Chrome bug reports

Comment: Almost same version but Windows 7 64bit, seems to be a specific problem with the MacOSX Version.